# How did the people of Marley steal 7 of the 9 original titans?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The story of Attack on Titan says the Eldian Empire grew unstable due to internal conflicts between the families with the power of the Titans, and collapsed during the Great Titan War a century ago, and that Eldia lost 7 of the 9 Titans to the nation of Marley.

How did the people of Marley steal 7 of the 9 original titans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Heavy Spoilers

We know that there were some people who defected to Marley. Chief among those would be the [Tybur family](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Tybur_family), which brought at least one of the nine titans with them. It's possible other Eldians fled to Marley as well, and possibly fought for them against King Fritz.

By the time we see Grisha Yeager as a child, Marley already had Eldian ghettos. That means enough Eldians had left for Marley to fill them at some point during the Great Titan War (since the Marleyans look down upon the Eldians and segregate them socially). Thus, Marley could capture a wielder and have their loyal Eldians eat them to gain that power (Marley would grant them special status if they did so).